# Why is there an attribute error when im trying to import Instaloader?

Tags: python, instagram, instaloader

I got an error saying AttributeError: 'LockedStream' object has no attribute 'encoding' when im trying to import Instaloader. Anyone seems to know why?

[Here's the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPojM.png)

Been searching on github and here in stackoverflow but can't seem to find a solution

Comment: Please include the code your're working with. Do not post the code or error as images.

Comment: Instaloader apparently doesn't work in Jupyter (and probably other IDEs, as well) - see https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader/issues/443 for a bug report with no resolution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.